# Fingerprint image is too small

Tags: c#, image-processing, fingerprint

I am using SourceAFIS for fingerprint verification in .net framework. When i take an image form my desktop, it works fine. But when i use the same image form my localhost server, i cannot load the image and the following error is shown inside 'Enroll' function:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in SourceAFIS.dll
>   Additional information: Fingerprint image is too small.

here is my Code:

```
  static MyPerson Enroll(string filename, string name)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enrolling {0}...", name);

        // Initialize empty fingerprint object and set properties
        MyFingerprint fp = new MyFingerprint();
        fp.Filename = filename;
        // Load image from the file
        //Console.WriteLine(" Image size = {0} x {1} (width x height)", fp.Image.GetLength(1), fp.Image.GetLength(0));
        Console.WriteLine(" Loading image from {0}...", filename);
        BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(filename, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        //Console.WriteLine(" Image size = {0} x {1} (width x height)", fp.Image.GetLength(1), fp.Image.GetLength(0));
        fp.AsBitmapSource = image;
        // Above update of fp.AsBitmapSource initialized also raw image in fp.Image
        // Check raw image dimensions, Y axis is first, X axis is second
        Console.WriteLine(" Image size = {0} x {1} (width x height)", fp.Image.GetLength(1), fp.Image.GetLength(0));

        // Initialize empty person object and set its properties
        MyPerson person = new MyPerson();
        person.Name = name;
        // Add fingerprint to the person
        person.Fingerprints.Add(fp);

        // Execute extraction in order to initialize fp.Template
        Console.WriteLine(" Extracting template...");
        Afis.Extract(person);
        // Check template size
        Console.WriteLine(" Template size = {0} bytes", fp.Template.Length);

        return person;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initialize SourceAFIS
        Afis = new AfisEngine();
        // Enroll some people
        List<MyPerson> database = new List<MyPerson>();
        database.Add(Enroll("http://localhost:6060/PhpProject2/img/img2.jpg", "Second"));
     }
```

Would you please tell me how to solve the issue?

Comment: You did not show any code. I'm afraid there are good programmers here, but none of them has telepathic powers. **Show** your **code**.

Comment: Code Added. Thanks

Comment: so the image dimensions after loading are the same as for the working image?